Does there exist a number $z$ algebraic over $ℚ$ and a prime $p$ such that $\operatorname{MinDeg}(p,z)\notinℕ$?
Let $\mathbb P$ denote the set of primes.
Let $\operatorname{A^*}$ denote the set of (complex) numbers algebraic over $ℚ$
Let $p\in\mathbb P$ and $z,w\in\operatorname{A^*}$
Let $p^ℤ[z]$ denote the set of univariate nonconstant polynomials (allowing subtraction of terms) in $z$ whose (nonzero) coefficients are integer powers of $p$
Let $F(z)\in p^ℤ[z]$ such that $F(w)=0$
Let $\operatorname{MinDeg}: \mathbb P \times A^* \rightarrow ℕ \cup \infty:= \min${$\deg(F)$} if $F$ exists and $\infty$ otherwise

I believe that this question is equivalent to the question (1)
Let $N\inℕ$
Let $a_i\inℤ\cup${$-\infty$} for $i=0,...,N$ such that $a_N\neq-\infty$
Let $b_i\inℤ$  for $i=0,...,N$
Define $$G_N(p,z)=\sum_{k=0}^{N}(-1)^{b_k}p^{a_k}z^k$$
For every prime $p$ and every algebraic number $w$, does (2) always have an answer? $\tag1$
After choosing some $p$ and some $w$, what is the minimum natural number $N$ such that there exists a pair of sequences of length $N+1$ given by $a_0,...,a_N$ and $b_0,...,b_N$ satisfying $\tag2$
$$G_N(p,w)=\sum_{k=0}^{N}(-1)^{b_k}p^{a_k}w^k=0$$

For an example of the $\operatorname{MinDeg}$ map being used, suppose $p$ is any prime and $w$ is $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$
Then
$$\operatorname{MinDeg}(p,\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})=2$$
since $$p^0(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^2-p^0(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})-p^0=0$$
and no such linear example exists for any prime $p$

Additionally, note that for all $n\inℤ$ and $m\inℤ\setminus${$0$} we have $\forall p\in\mathbb P$:

$$\operatorname{MinDeg}(p,p^n)=1$$ since you can choose $p^k(z)-p^{k+n}=p^k(p^n)-p^{k+n}=0$ for any integer $k$

Suppose $n$ and $m$ are coprime.
Then $$\operatorname{MinDeg}(p,p^{n/m})=m$$ since you can choose
$p^k(z)^m-p^{k+n}(z)^0=p^k(p^{n/m})^m-p^{k+n}=0$ for any integer $k$


and $\operatorname{MinDeg}(p,p^{n/m})$ is always greater than or equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial of $p^{n/m}$ over $ℚ$ (e.g. $m≤\operatorname{MinDeg}(p,p^{n/m})≤m$ )

$$\operatorname{MinDeg}(p,0)=1$$ since you can choose $(a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1)=(-\infty,k,1,0)$  so that
$p^k(z)-p^{-\infty}=p^k(0)-0=0$ for any integer $k$

$$\operatorname{MinDeg}(p,w)$$ is always greater than or equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial of $w$ over $ℚ$



I would not think there was a name for this.  Note that it's not defined for most $a\in \mathbb C$.  After all, if there is any such $F$, then $a$ must be algebraic.  And even for algebraic numbers....is there any such $F$ for a root of $x^2+2x+3$?

Note:  $(x^2+2x+3)\times (x-1)=x^3+x^2+x-3$ so that one works (assuming you allow negative coefficients, which isn't clear from your post), which leads to the question as to whether or not it works for all $a\in \overline {\mathbb Q}$.

The standard name for $\mathbb C^{**}$ is, however, $\mathbb Q[i].$ It forms a ring.

Do we always know there is at least one $F$ for every $p,a?$ Or should the codomain of this function be $\mathbb N\cup{\infty}?$ It seems by the rational root theorem there isn't always at least on $F.$

The rational root theorem says that an integer polynomial with root $a=\frac16$ has a lead coefficient a multiple of $6,$ and hence there cannot be an $F$ for any $p.$
